# 与えられた２つの時間の差を１時間単位で返す関数を作りたい

Tags: python, python3

以下のような２つの時間 (start, end) が与えられた時, その時間の差分は3時間です。

```
import datetime

start = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 0)
end = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 4, 0)
```

これを利用して以下のような関数を作りたいのですが, 調べても解決策がないため質問させていただきます。

```
def INPUT(start,end):
    #ここの処理がわからない

#欲しい結果: startとendの間の時間を返す関数を作りたい
INPUT(start,end) --> [2021-01-01 01:00:00, 2021-01-01 02:00:00, 2021-01-01 03:00:00, 2021-01-01 04:00:00]
```

ここでstart,endは必ず時間ごとに区切りがついているものとします。
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def INPUT(start, end):
    return [start + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range((end - start).seconds // 3600 + 1)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 0)
    end = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 4, 0)

    ret = INPUT(start,end)
    print([d.strftime("%F %T") for d in ret])

#
['2021-01-01 01:00:00', '2021-01-01 02:00:00', '2021-01-01 03:00:00', '2021-01-01 04:00:00']
```

Answer (score 0):

以下で、いかがでしょうか。

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

start = dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 0)
end = dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 4, 0)
print(start, end)

# １時間間隔
date_list = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='H')
display(date_list)
print('Type:', isinstance(date_list[0], dt.datetime))
```

◇出力
2021-01-01 01:00:00 2021-01-01 04:00:00
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01 01:00:00', '2021-01-01 02:00:00',
'2021-01-01 03:00:00', '2021-01-01 04:00:00'],
dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
Type: True